# spark sql date_add failing with INTERVAL in sql command

Tags: apache-spark-sql

PySpark Sql (version 2) and I'm using a sql command to execute it from a file:

Snippet of the sql:

```
WHERE TO_DATE(mac.StartDatetime) <= date_add(ec.AdmissionDatetime, INTERVAL 2 HOUR)
```

Error:

cannot resolve 'date_add(CAST(ec.`AdmissionDatetime` AS DATE), interval 2 hours)' due to data type mismatch: argument 2 requires int type, however, 'interval 2 hours' is of calendarinterval type.;

What am I missing?  All the documentation seems to talk about it being implemented and should work.  At least from the api standpoint.  I've seen closed tickets for 1.4 that implemented the date_add and time_add.

I've tried time_add but get an unrecognized function error.  We keep our sql in separate files and have built a framework to execute the sql for our process.